# How can I generate or add resourcedesigner.cs file in a dotnet Maui project?

Tags: xamarin, maui, zebra-scanners

I'm trying to add `resourcedesigner.cs` file to my Maui project.

[image: here's a snippet of the code :]

I know the file can be generated but what I'm trying to do is to take some files from a Xamarin project and put it in my Maui project to implement the scan of zebra with intent.

I tried adding the file manually but I got some error of Xamarin essentials missing and I was told not to add Xamarin nuget packages to my Maui project.

Comment: Could you provide error messages about it?

Answer (score 0):

Maui Internally Handlers `ResourceDesigner` you don't need that class add the files in your `Resource` folder in your Android project rest should automatically work, for an example you can check my library here:

https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/tree/master/MAUI.FreakyControls/MAUI.FreakyControls/Platforms/Android/Resources

Notice how it has a Resources folder with the general Android folders but no Designer file... but it still is able to use Resources.